# Convert text to Image - calculating exact text width

Tags: java

I need to convert text to an Image. I found some code in an other thread which I modified a little bit.
Locally all is working fine. The text ends exactelly at the end of the image. But on the server (running openJDK) not the entire text is visible (2.5 letters are missing).

I tried to calculate the right width on different ways. e.g.

```
FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
Rectangle2D r2d = font.getStringBounds(row, frc);
int width = (int)Math.ceil(r2d.getWidth());

int width = g2d.getFontMetrics(g2d.getFont()).stringWidth(row);
```

But the calculated width is allways the same.

```
public static BufferedImage text2Image(Font font, Color textColor, Color backgroundColor, String...textRows) {
    BufferedImage helperImg = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = helperImg.createGraphics();

    g2d.setFont(font);
    FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

    int width = 0;
    for(String row : textRows) {
        if(fm.stringWidth(row) > width) {
            width = fm.stringWidth(row);
        }
    }
    int height = fm.getHeight() * textRows.length;
    g2d.dispose();

    BufferedImage finalImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    g2d = finalImg.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(backgroundColor);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
    g2d.setFont(font);
    fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
    g2d.setColor(textColor);
    int y = fm.getAscent();
    for(String row : textRows) {
        g2d.drawString(row, 0, y);
        y += fm.getHeight();
    }
    g2d.dispose();

    return finalImg;
}
```

What is the best way to calculate the nessecary width that works platform independent? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try setting the rendering hints before calculating the size, not sure if it will make a difference, but the rendering hints can effect the size of the output

Answer (score 0):

@MadProgrammer

Thanks for the hint!
That it is. This two hints has to be set additionally before calculating the size.

```
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
```